# What regex will match for takes two parts of a string (Between symbols but without these symobos in the result)?

Tags: regex

I was looking for the answer in stackoverflow but I couldn't find a case like the mine. For me is really difficult regex expressions.

I have one string like this (without quotation marks (")):
1) `"09:10,10:00"`
2) `"11:40,12:35"`

And for each one, I need to fill four variables with numeric the parts (without quotation marks ("))
1)
    `variable1_hourFrom="09"`
    `variable2_hourTo="10"`
    `variable3_minuteFrom="10"`
    `variable4_minuteto="00"`

2)
    `variable1_hourFrom="11"`
    `variable2_hourTo="12"`
    `variable3_minuteFrom="40"`
    `variable4_minuteto="35"`

I'm using regex expressions function from BigQuery `REGEXP_EXTRACT(variable, r'regex_expresion')`

Thanks for the help and regards!

Comment: Maybe https://regex101.com/r/IdUyDR/1

Answer (score -1):

Use parentheses to group matches.  The match `.groups()` method will return the items matched.  Answer demo in Python:

```
import re

items = "09:10,10:00","11:40,12:35"

for item in items:
    m = re.match(r'(\d\d):(\d\d),(\d\d):(\d\d)',item)
    hourFrom,minuteFrom,hourTo,minuteTo = m.groups()
    print(hourFrom,minuteFrom,hourTo,minuteTo)
```

```
09 10 10 00
11 40 12 35
```